# Maven archetype - optional property, empty by default

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-archetype

I want to be able to generate a project from my archetype with **one of the properties being empty by default**, or populated if specified so on the command line.

This is my `archetype-metadata.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="compilerVersion"/>
        <requiredProperty key="dependencyClassifier">
            <defaultValue></defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

This is not working. If there is any non-whitespace value in `dependencyClassifier`, then it works flawlessly. However, I cannot get it to work with the default value being "empty".

The error I get when `defaultValue` is empty/null is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype com.avast.archetype:compile-java:1.0.21 is not configured
[ERROR] Property dependencyClassifier is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Alternatively, I would accept being able to pass an empty-value (or "whitespace" value) on the command line. Again, using `"-DdependencyClassifier= "` does not work.

How do I specify a property should be empty by default?

Thanks

---

What I want to achieve with this is to be able to create a project from an archetype, which contains a dependency declaration:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${dependencyVersion}</version>
            <classifier>${dependencyClassifier}</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and I need to be able to instantiate `${dependencyClassifier}` on archetype creation. This is possible for `${dependencyVersion}`, because that will never be empty. Classifier, however, should be empty by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I successed meeting your requirements:

In the template `pom.xml` file for the to-be-generated Maven project, place an empty property, but don't use it as placeholder of the `classifier` value, there you will still use the archetype `requiredProperty` placeholder as following:

```
<properties>
    <!-- empty placeholder, document it accordingly -->
    <empty.property></empty.property>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>${dependencyClassifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, in your `archetype-metadata.xml` have the following:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="dependencyClassifier">
        <defaultValue>${empty.property}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

Note the matchings:

- The `${empty.property}` default value here is just a non existing property for the Archetype Plugin, which is accepted (an empty value would not work indeed).
- The `dependencyClassifier` now has a default value, which is `${empty.property}`
- On the generated project though, `empty.property` would be empty (if `dependencyClassifier` was not specified during the `mvn archetype:generate` call), because it exists as Maven property, with empty value, which makes the whole valid for Maven: the property value injected by the archetype is a declared property in the final pom and as such not breaking anything.
- The classifier will hence have either `dependencyClassifier` value (specified at runtime) or `empty.property` (its default value), which is empty
- An empty classifier is treated by Maven as no classifier, as such providing us both behaviors.

To summarize:

Invoking

```
mvn archetype:generate ... -DdependencyClassifier=something
```

Would effectively populate the `classifier` element with `something`, our desired classifier at runtime.

Instead, not specifying any value will leave `classifier` with `${empty.property}`, that is, empty. An Maven will no look for any classifier (nor complain).

The only drawback of this approach is to keep an `empty.property` property for no much meaning in your final `pom.xml`, it's a trick which may shock some purists, but does the job.

Comment: I did not realize I can pass a property to `<defaultValue>`! I will test this and accept the answer as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: @MartinMelka you can pass a property but it will not be treated as a property by the Archetype Plugin (or the Velocity template) but simply as a string. Of course once it gets into the final real `pom.xml` it will then be treated as a property and there is the trick :)

Comment: this won't help you if you are trying to conditionally add the entire dependency as a whole.  In my case, if "-DdatabaseType=mysql" is set, I want to add the mysql jdbc driver dep.  If no databaseType is set, I don't want the dependency added at all

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem, though it does not produce a *clean* output file (but it works...).

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar case and, applied to your use case, solved it like this:

In `archetype-metadata.xml`, define `_UNDEFINED_` (or some other magic string) as the default value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
  <requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="compilerVersion"/>
    <requiredProperty key="dependencyClassifier">
      <defaultValue>_UNDEFINED_</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

In the `<dependency>` section of the template `pom.xml`, use a [VTL](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html) `#if` directive:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>${dependencyVersion}</version>
#if( ${dependencyClassifier} != "_UNDEFINED_" )
    <classifier>${dependencyClassifier}</classifier>
#end
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So your final `pom.xml` just does not contain a `<classifier>` definition *at all* if you omit `-DdependencyClassifier=something` with `archetype:generate`. Which I guess is definitely satisfying purists. Even if the code in the archetype itself may not.

Note: According to the [dependency list of archetype-common](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/dependencies.html), the current version 3.1.2 of Maven archetype plugin uses [Apache Velocity Engine 1.7](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/).

Comment: To me this solution is better since it produces a clean generated file, without any quirks. You need to learn a bit of Velocity #if/#else/#end but that's actually good. +1